# есть ли в Pyqt5 специальный объект для таких окон? Если нет то как это можно реализовать?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

[image: Пример окошка]

Как возможно реализовать данное окно на qt?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt5/pyqt5_qmenubar_qmenu_qaction_widgets.htm